# Angular 4 setTimeout does not wait

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

I am creating an angular 4 app with typescript.

I'm having a function that needs to be executed every 10 seconds untill a specified stopcondition. I created a loop with some testcode using setTimeout to see if it would work.

My Testcode:

```
public run() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        setTimeout(this.timer,3000);
        i++;
    }
}

public timer(){
    console.log("done")
}
```

However this seems to wait for 3 seconds, or browser is just slow...
and then it prints 4 times done. So the code isn't working. Am I doing this wrong or are there other possibilities to do this kind of things?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you are using Angular you can probably do this in a much simpler way using [`takeWhile`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takewhile.md):

```
Observable.interval(10000)
    .takeWhile(() => !stopCondition)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        // This will be called every 10 seconds until `stopCondition` flag is set to true
    })
```

Comment: when I try this I get an error: ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.interval is not a function

Comment: That's ridiculous I imported { Observable } from rxjs/Observable, that did not work...Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @fangio don't ever import `from "rxjs"`. That will import all the Observable static methods and operators, which will make your application bundle way bigger than it should be. Use the import you had, and add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile'`;`. That will only import the methods and operators that you actually use.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're doing it wrong: you have a loop telling 4 times in a row to execute `timer()` 3 seconds later, from now.

To do what you want, you would have to reschedule the next timer each time `timer()` is called, or, more simply, to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```
let count = 0;
const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
    this.timer();
    count++;
    if (count >= 4) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Note that, since you're using angular, using observables would be muuuch easier:

```
Observable.interval(3000).take(4).subscribe(() => this.timer());
```

Comment: Just for my own reference, how can you make the `Observable` interval stop if a certain condition has been met. For instance when a class field becomes `true`

Comment: `takeWhile(() => !this.someField)`

Comment: Lovely! It's like they have a solution for everything :)

Comment: @JBNizet Could you please show how to import the libraries correctly?

Answer (score 6):

I did it with **Angular 6**. This code requests every 5 seconds to get the progress of rendering. It will stops sending request when the progress reaches %100.

```
import {interval} from "rxjs";

getProgress(searchId): void{
const subscription = interval(5000)
  .subscribe(()=>{
    //Get progress status from the service every 5 seconds
    this.appService.getProgressStatus(searchId)
      .subscribe((jsonResult:any)=>{
          //update the progress on UI 

          //cancel subscribe until it reaches %100
          if(progressPercentage === 100)
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        },
        error => {
          //show errors
        }
      );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed not the way to use an `async` method. The `while` loop just goes 4 times through it in one go, and initiate the 4 timers. Which will output simultaneously as well in 3 seconds. You can however leverage the `await` and `async` functionality from TypeScript:

```
public stopCondition: boolean = false;

public async run(): Promise<void> {
    while (!this.stopCondition) {
       await new Promise<void>(resolve => {
           setTimeout(resolve, 10000);
       });
       this.execute();
    }
    console.log('done');
}

public execute(): void {
    if ('whatever should trigger your stop condition') {
       this.stopCondition = true;
    }
}
```

This will run the `execute` method after every 10 seconds, for as long as the `stopCondition === false`. When the `stopCondition === true` it will output `done`.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to remove "void" as not supported ES5 for an async function.  But the above approach worked.  Thank you for taking time to contribute this.

Comment: @Kirk my bad indeed. Should be `Promise<void>` for typescript, and ES5 does not support typings, so you should remove it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `setInterval(hander:(args:any[]),ms:Number,args:any[])` which is one of the methods of `OnInit`.

```
setInterval(a=>{
  alert("yes....");
},10000,[]);
```

Will show alert "yes" after 10 secs.

Comment: have you tried this inside an angular fucntion that toggles a boolean attribute?   Doesnt seem to work on mine...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct behavior. You have synchronous loop which created 4 delayed actions and ends this loop. It happens in few milliseconds. So all 4 delayed actions are registered to be started in 3 seconds, about at same time.

So in 3 secs you will receive all 4 responses from this delayed actions.

If you want to have consequence call execution (first after 3 sec, then second after first) consider to use promises for this and call new promise withh 3 second delay after previous completion.

```
fisrtPromise
   .then(secondPromise)
   .then(thirdPromise);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling setTimeout inside while loop and because of asynchronous execution of statements it will not wait to execute Timer function before going to next iteration. You can achieve required functionality by using below code

```
public run() {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (++i === 4) {                
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else {
            this.timer();
        }
    }, 3000);

}

public timer() {
    console.log("done")
}
```