# Can someone explain what Observable.timeout and takewhile do?

Tags: angular, observable

I came upon this piece of code that I can't really understand what it means, even though I used it in my implementation and works fine.

```
Observable.interval(10000)
    .takeWhile(() => !stopCondition)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        // This will be called every 10 seconds until `stopCondition` flag is set to true
    })
```

The original post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057567/7316937

Can anyone be so kind to explain to me what this does? I can't find any meaningful information on the internet that makes me understand what this does.
Thank you to anyone who will answer.

Answer (score 1):

`interval(10000)` emits an event every 10 seconds (which causes the  function passed to `subscribe(...)` to be called every 10 secs)

`takeWhile(...)` closes the observable when `stopCondition` becomes `true`, which means no more events are emitted and the subscription ends.

Comment: _closes the observable_ - unsubscribes is maybe better word here. because _means no more events are emitted_ - unless the observable is hot, in that case an observable will continue emitting events